# Unavailable plugin during migration to craft 3

Tags: craft3, plugins, migration

During a migration from craft 2 to craft 3, I stumble in 3 issues with plugins.

1. Plugins are not available in craft 3. For example,"instablog" plugin
2. Reinstall paid license plugins.
3. Custom plugins.
   What should we handle in different cases?

Answer (score 1):

When updating from Craft 2 to Craft 3, you will need to make a handful of decisions on how to handle plugins that don't have a clear migration path. The answer may be different for each plugin, depending on various circumstances.

1. Moving forward with dead plugins, you'll generally need to...

   - Replace it with a completely different plugin, or
   - Port some version of the necessary code into a custom module, or
   - Figure out how to replicate that behavior using native Craft features, so you can skip using a plugin or module completely.
2. If you bought a Craft 2 license for the plugin, see if there is a way to transfer your license to Craft 3. How this is handled will vary greatly between plugin vendors, so you'll need to follow up with the plugin vendor directly.
3. For custom plugins, you'll want to convert those into a [module](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/module-guide.html). It's like a plugin, [but different](https://nystudio107.com/blog/enhancing-a-craft-cms-3-website-with-a-custom-module).